# Autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

hi every one i need simple auto suggest code i have tried with  jquery.autocomplete.js am not getting what i need to do
code :- index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  

 <html>  

 <head>  

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />  

     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>  

     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>  

 </head>  

 <body>  

     <div style="width: 300px; margin: 50px auto;">  

         <b>Country</b>   : <input type="text" id="country" name="country" class="input_text"/>  

     </div>  



 </body>  

 <script>  

     jQuery(function(){  

         $("#country").autocomplete("list.jsp");  

     });  

 </script>  


 </html> 


and list.jsp
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>  

 <%@page import="java.util.List"%>  

 <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>  

 <%  

    String countries[] = {  

                             "Afghanistan",  

                            "Albania",  

                             "Algeria",  

                            "Andorra",  

                             "Angola",  

                             "Antigua and Barbuda",  

                             "Argentina",  

                             "Armenia",  

                             "Yemen",  

                             "Zambia",  

                             "Zimbabwe" 

                             };  



     String query = (String)request.getParameter("q");  

     System.out.println("1"+request.getParameterNames().nextElement());  

     response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");  

     int cnt=1;  

     for(int i=0;i<countries.length;i++)  

     {  

         if(countries[i].toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))  

        {  

            out.print(countries[i]+"\n");  

             if(cnt>=10)  
                break;  

             cnt++;  

         }  

     }  

 %>
```

there is one more style.css is there but it is not showing anything while execution
note all source file is present in same folder please tell me where am lacking

Comment: It's not clear where the problem is at the moment. Try and simplify the solution to narrow down the possible location of the problem. First prove that the client side is working ok by eliminating the request to the server side using the "source" option - $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({source: ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Andorra"]}); Then check that the server side is working ok by calling it with a simply $.ajax call. Then try and fit the two together. It's likely that the format of the results returned by the server is different from that expected by the autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation of autocomplete, you need a javascript json object. This is a container for all your data. I miss this container in your source code which you have posted.

If you click on [Demos of utocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete#Demos), scroll to the end of this page. I think the last demo represents what you look for.

Comment: i dnt know how to use this really am new guy in this can u give me simple code for this its very urgent requirement

Comment: It can't be that urgent if a newcomer to the technology has been asked to implement it.

Comment: its my part of project and i dnt know about autocomplete option

Comment: k tell me where i need to put u r code atleast where u missed this

Answer (score 0):

```
<% 
 String countries[] = {"Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Antigua and Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"};
 String query = (String)request.getParameter("q");
 response.setHeader("Content-Type","text/html"); 
 String javascriptContent = new String ("");
 int cnt = countries.length;
 if(cnt > 10)
 {
  cnt = 10;
 }
 for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
 { 
    if(countries[i].toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
    {
        javascriptContent.concat(countries.get(i));
        if (i < (cnt -1))
        {
            javascriptContent.concat(",");
        } 
    }
} 
%>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.bgiframe.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var data = "<%=  javascriptContent %>".split(",");
            $("#country").autocomplete(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <b>Country</b>   : <input type="text" id="country" name="country" class="input_text"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here they are and have fun. I copied athe html source code from the mainpage of autocomplete. Please check the java syntax first.

Comment: displaying error An error occurred at line: 1 in the jsp file: /ajax/post.jsp
Generated servlet error:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.0\work\Standalone\localhost\CORE\org\apache\jsp\ajax\post_jsp.java:55: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : method getString (int)
location: class java.lang.String[]
    javascriptContent.concat(countries.getString(i));   
                                      ^
1 error

Comment: its displaying error message i have stored it in single post.jsp page

Comment: As you can see, there are no imports. So add the imports to the page. If you don't know appropirate imports use google.com ant type in the keywords "java api".
For the method concat() you need the import 'java.lang.String'